# How to stop out of order results in this query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE FOO
(
  "ID" NUMBER(30,0),
  "CREATION_TIME" TIMESTAMP(6),
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
  "TRANSACTION_NUMBER" NUMBER(30,0)
);
```

I have a requirement to get a max of 100 entries that have a CREATION_TIME > 30 days in the past, per NAME. Also regardless of CREATION_TIME I have to return at least one entry with the highest ID. For example if all entries are older than 30 days I should return 1 entry with the highest ID. I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (WITH rws AS (SELECT o.*, row_number() over (PARTITION BY NAME ODER BY ID DESC) rn
  FROM ORDERS o WHERE CREATION_TIME > sysdate-30)
  SELECT * FROM rws WHERE rn<=100)
UNION
  SELECT * FROM (WITH rws AS (SELECT o.*, row_number() over (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID DESC) RN
  FROM ORDERS o ORDER BY ID DESC)
  SELECT * FROM rws WHERE rn<=1)
```

The problem is there is no guarantee that IDs are increasing with time. For the most part they are, but there can be a case like:

```
ID, CREATION_TIME, NAME,   TRANSACTION_NUMBER
---------------------------------------------
4,  today          foo,    111
2,  29 days ago    foo,    122
3,  30 days ago    foo,    123
1,  31 days ago    foo,    133
```

In this case the query would incorrectly return 3 entries (ID=2,3,4) when it should return only the top two, (ID=4,2). I have tried modifying the query to fix this but I'm out of ideas. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Note due to production risk I can't make changes to the database, I have to solve this with my select query. The query has to run on H2 and Oracle.

Comment: In your example it is not clear (to me) why it should return 4, 2. You said it should return the top id (4) and any records > 30 days - so shouldn't the correct answer be 4, 3, 1?

Comment: @NickW `1` is outside 30 days and is not the maximum ID value, why would it be returned?

Comment: Because you stated you wanted records with “ CREATION_TIME > 30 days in the past” i.e. more than 30 days ago

Comment: @NickW I think it might just be bad wording on my side. I meant the CREATION_TIME should be greater than the CREATION_TIME of a record 30 days in the past. E.g. get the data for the last 30 days. I am thinking in terms of epoch time stamps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT o.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY creation_time DESC) AS rn,
         MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS max_id
  FROM   ORDERS o
)
WHERE (CREATION_TIME > sysdate-30 AND rn <= 100)
OR    (id = max_id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b99f56194ffdd9ffa385414ee19f3a1)*